# How can I get this href value?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to get the value "3 Sent" from the hmtl below. How can I do this?

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs some-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#accepted" data-toggle="tab">1 Accepted</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#sent" data-toggle="tab">3 Sent</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

EDIT: Apologies everyone, I wasn't clear on what I was after.

The value "3 Sent" changes all the time, can be "1 Sent, 2 Sent" etc. It is a clickable link so I want to be able to click on it.,

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the `href` value which is `#sent`? or `3 Sent`?

Comment: document.querySelector("a[href='#sent']").innerHTML ?

Comment: Where do you write your code? In a selenium project or else do you want to get value in JavaScript?

Comment: Code is written in a Selenium project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible with `xpath` text based search. I believe you are looking for a selector

```
//a[.='3 Sent']
```

**Edit**

Just simply use css selector then,

```
a[href='#sent']
```

Comment: Correct. But, I am little confused about what OP's asking.

Comment: Simple as that eh, Saifur? :-) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
 The anchor tag when gets clicked it search for the text

```
$('.nav li a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Value is " + $(this).text());
});
```

Comment: While this post provides helpful code, it would also greatly help to include some explanation as to why this code works, which would help not just the original poster, but also other people with the same problem (not to mention help you get more reputation!)

Comment: @ShreyGupta thank you  so much . I will remind it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get it using below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('li').find('a').each(function() {

       if($(this).attr('href')=="#sent")
       {
           alert($(this).text());
       }


   });
});
```

**[Here is JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c4hxbct1/)**

Answer (score 0):

From the class `.active` in the next `list` element get the text in anchor.

```js
var textInAnchor = document.querySelector(".active + li a").innerHTML;

alert(textInAnchor)
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs some-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#accepted" data-toggle="tab">1 Accepted</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#sent" data-toggle="tab">3 Sent</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

from the class `.some-tabs` find the child `list` element in the second position then return his anchor text

```js
var textInAnchor = document.querySelector(".some-tabs > li:nth-child(2) a").innerHTML;

alert(textInAnchor)
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs some-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#accepted" data-toggle="tab">1 Accepted</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#sent" data-toggle="tab">3 Sent</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Get the `href` with `value = #sent` the return the text

```js
var textInAnchor = document.querySelector("[href='#sent']").innerHTML;
alert(textInAnchor)
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs some-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#accepted" data-toggle="tab">1 Accepted</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#sent" data-toggle="tab">3 Sent</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```